# Increment paged on WP_Query

Tags: php, posts, wp-query

What's the proper way to increment 'paged' under a WP_Query call? This is what I have below:

```php
    $custom_query = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'employee',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => 1,
    ]);

    foreach ($custom_query->posts as $employee) {
        var_dump($employee);
    }
```

`var_dump($employee)` returns my first 10 records, but I can't figure out how to increment or target 'paged'.

I've tried doing `$custom_query['paged']++;` but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: if you want all results, you can use `"nopaging" => TRUE,` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: @Kaperto, I actually want to loop through 10 records at a time - I have additional code that will save the settings, I just don't know how to increment paged or target it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `WP_Query` instance with the updated arguments. I will usually write it like this

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'employee',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => 1,
];
$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    // your logic goes here
    // foreach ($query->posts as $custom_stuff) {}

    // prepare for next loop iteration
    $args['paged']++;
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
}
```

When the first run is done, `$args['paged']` is updated and the `$query` variable is updated with a new `WP_Query` instance. if `$query->have_posts()` is true, the loop will then continue.

Comment: Thanks so much @kero, just what I was looking for.